# Customise app title

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I am trying to implement custom app title. I made a custom layout to change the title text color to white.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/textView1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:paddingLeft="0dp"
     android:text="@string/title_activity_main"
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
     android:textColor="@color/textColorWhite"/>
```

And in the activity onCreate()

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
setFeatureDrawableResource(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON, R.drawable.my_icon);
getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.layout_custom_app_title);
```

It fails to work on Android 2.2 device. However, I tested successfully on version 4.0

Does anyone got any workaround?

**EDIT:**

```
<style name="customWindowTitle">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/textColorWhite</item>
</style>

<style name="LightThemeSelector" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/app_background</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/textColorBlack</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/customWindowTitle</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Yes. Don't set a custom view just because you want a different text color. Change it with the help of a custom theme.

Comment: is it possible to change only app title color using themes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this easily by using custom theme. To do so here is the procedure

in style.xml add

```
<resources>
    <style name="CustomWindowTitleBackground">
        <item name="android:background">@color/textColorWhite</item>
        // here you can add other attributes
    </style>

    <style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:windowTitleSize">25dip</item>
        <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/CustomWindowTitleBackground</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

and in AndroidManifest.xml add

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/CustomTheme">
```

Comment: So will this be applied all across the app? I already have a theme for the app. Now I need a different text color than the one mentioned in custom theme to be set for application title.

Comment: Yeah it worked! But I couldn't draw the reason how it did. android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle is never a standard parameter. Then how come it changed exactly the title text color alone?

Comment: it is just setting  title bar style and as you can see it inherits the android:Theme.. the other attribute can be set in the first style

Comment: See my edited question! I am explicitly setting text color to black. Apart from that, a customized style bit sets text color back to white. But, in real, all text except app title has become black. I can't get that point

Comment: because in second style you are setting the color as black

Comment: In android:textSize, textSize is like a keyword which has a pre-defined meaning. It sets the color of all text to the SET value whereas android:customWindowTitle is user-defined. What has done in that user-defined style is that the text color is set again. So in effect, the text color is white. My question is that why wasn't it get overwritten?